# Could the Bifrost have destroyed Thanos's ship in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, during the Battle on Earth, if Thor had summoned the Bifrost while standing under Thanos's ship, would the Bifrost have easily punched a hole through it which may have led to the ship exploding?

If one shot wouldn't have done it, then perhaps Thor could have flown to different points below the ship and summoned the Bifrost multiple times in order to take it out.

Comment: What makes you think that Bifrost destroy anything in its way? It was never portrayed to do so in any of the MCU movies as far as I remember...

Comment: @Torsten Link, in the movie Thor, Loki had used the Bifrost to try to destroy the planet Jotunheim where it began ripping through the center of that planet. So, if it can destroy a planet it should be able to punch a hole through a ship.

Comment: OK. Sorry. Forgot about that...

Comment: Lol, like [this](https://youtu.be/AaD1r8eqF-U?t=30)?

Comment: @Möoz, yes, like that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly but I don't think Stormbreaker has the ability to keep the Bifrost open to be able to destroy the ship. We see in *Thor* that it is the act of leaving the Bifrost open which could have destroyed Jotunheim and not having used the Bifrost to "cut through" the planet.

> **Volstagg:** Couldn't you just leave the bridge open for us?
>
> **Heimdall:** To keep this bridge open would unleash the full power of the Bifrost and destroy Jotunheim with you upon it.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

Stormbreaker, however, only seems to be able to summon the Bifrost so it would appear that it probably wouldn't be able to keep it open.

> **Eitri:** It's a mold. A king's weapon. Meant to be the greatest in Asgard. In theory, it could even summon the Bifrost.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

The only time I can think of when we see the Bifrost cut through something is at the beginning of *Thor: Ragnarok* when it cuts off the dragon's head. However, the dragon's head was in the "portal" type area for being transferred and its body was not.

It's unclear if the Bifrost would cut through anything in its path. In fact, if anything it seems it would "dodge" what is in its path as we see at the start of *Avengers: Infinity War* when Heimdall sends Hulk back to Earth. The path it takes is not direct but curves a bit dodging planets. Also when Heimdall does this the Bifrost only sends Hulk along the path and doesn't rip a hole in the ship they're on.

Comment: those are good points you make, especially about the Bifrost curving around planets.

Comment: Also the Bifrost takes Hulk out of the super-damaged Asgardian ship, but apparently doesn’t harm it in the process.

Comment: [The _other_ time the Bifrost breaks something in its path](https://youtu.be/VmU2QUUdNEw?t=75). The clip is cut short, but you see the car's bonnet fling into the landing room on Asgard at the other end.